# How can I retrieve product description using Amazon API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know how to retrieve the product description from the Amazon API? I have asked their forum with no success. I can access the detailed page URL from an ItemLookUp but then I have to screenscrape which is not ideal.

Answer (score 15):

Hey, I know this is a bit old, but I've found the EditorialReview part of the response contains the product description. I guess the cravet that Tom talks about still applies, but at least its a way to get to the description without reverting to screen scraping (which is never a good thing!) :)

See this page of the Amazon product API: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/

> EditorialReview Response Group
>
> For each item in the response, the
>   EditorialReview response group returns
>   Amazon's review of the item, which, on
>   the Detail page, is labeled the
>   Product Description.

No nasty screen scraping required! :)

Andy.

Comment: Unfortunately, for lots of products, there's no editorial review available via the API (though there's one on the product page on Amazon)

Comment: there's more. For some reason, amazon will give you EditorialReview after ItemSearch calls, while - evens for same asin - no EditorialReview when calling with ItemLookup. weird.

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve it like this apparently (wont work, wrong key):

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.de/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=1EYQH7NQ7HMKEGDPVZ82&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=3492233198&ResponseGroup=Large,ItemAttributes,Images,Offers,EditorialReview,Subjects,Reviews
```

Taken from [Amazon Developer Forum](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=67545):

> Similar issue was discussed at
>   http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=16331&tstart=0.
>   Amazon does not own all the content
>   that appears on the retail site and
>   some of it is licensed from third
>   parties who limit the ways in which
>   their intellectual property is allowed
>   to be reproduced.  As a result, we
>   need to filter out some editorial
>   reviews / contents from public
>   responses when querying via ECS.

So be careful screenscraping, it might be breaking copyright.  Also check that the data you are attempting to retrive is allowed.

Comment: unusual use of "Large" aside others ItemAttributes, Images, etc.